# How to disable username according to his id?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to disable username according to his id?  If I add disabled   It would disable all the array and not just a single value. How can I disable only a single value within an array?

```
              <div class="row">
             <?php foreach($userslist as  $user){ ?>
              <div class="col-xs-3">
              <select class="form-control" disabled>
                <option><?=$user['User']['username'];?><option>

              </select>
            </div><?php } ?>
            </div>`
```

Comment: [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an if statement

```
if (user_id == some_value) {
    <select class="form-control" disabled>
        <option><?=$user['User']['username'];?><option>
    </select>
} else {
    <select class="form-control">
        <option><?=$user['User']['username'];?><option>
    </select>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<?php foreach($userslist as  $user){ ?>
 <div class="col-xs-3">
 <select class="form-control">
    <?php if($user['User']['username'] == 'XXX'){?>
        <option disabled><?=$user['User']['username'];?><option>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <option ><?=$user['User']['username'];?><option>
    <?php } ?>
 </select>
</div><?php } ?>
</div>
```